# C# Convert decimal to string with specify format

Tags: c#, string, math, decimal

I need to convert decimal number a to string b folowing:

- b must be haven `'.'` character. Eg:

  - a = 12 -> b = "12.0"
  - a = 1.2 -> b = "1.2"
  - a = 1.234 -> b = "1.234"

How can I do that with 1 command?

- b must be haven exactly 10 character. Eg:

  - a = 101 -> b = "101.000000"
  - a = 1.234 -> b = "1.23400000"
  - a = 1.234567891 -> b = "1.23456789"

(Same question with 1)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
decimal a = 12;
var b = a.ToString("N1"); // 12.0

a = 1.2m;
b = a.ToString(); // 1.2

a = 101m;
b = a.ToString("N10"); // 101.0000000000

a = 1.234m;
b = a.ToString("N10"); // 1.2340000000
```

For the second part of your question - where you want a total length of 10 then:

```
decimal a = 1.234567891m;
int numberOfDigits = ((int)a).ToString().Length;
var b = a.ToString($"N{9 - numberOfDigits}"); //1.23456789

//Or before C# 6.0
var b = a.ToString("N" + (9 - numberOfDigits)); //1.23456789
```

Basically `((int)number).ToString().Length` gives you the amount of digits before the `.` (converting to int will remove the fractions) and then reducing that from the number of digits after the `.` (and also -1 for the decimal point itself)

Comment: In 2nd question, total characters of b is 10, not number of digits after '.'

Comment: For the 2nd one, it needs to consider when the total length > 10. You probably need an extension method for the 2nd one.

Comment: @GiladGreen what about decimal a = 12345678910m?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.ToString()` to do this task:

```
decimal aDecimalVal = 10.234m;
string decimalString = aDecimalVal.ToString("#.000"); // "10.234"
aDecimalVal.ToString("#.00"); // "10.23"
aDecimalVal.ToString("#.0000"); // "10.2340"
```

The number of `0` after the `.` in the format string will decide the number of places in the decimal string.

**Updates:** So you want to find the number of digits after the decimal points, So the changes in the code will be like the following:

```
decimal aDecimalVal = 10.2343455m;
int count = BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(aDecimalVal)[3])[2];
string formatString = String.Format("N{0}",count.ToString());
string decimalString = aDecimalVal.ToString(formatString); // "10.2343455"
```

Comment: but I don't know exact the number of digits after '.' character

Answer (score 1):

I manage to do it using double. Is this what you need?
I don't quite get the second part of your question.

```cs
double a = 12;
string b = a.ToString("0.0000000000######");
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want the result as a string, just parse it and format it to one decimal places:

```
string strTemp = 12;
double temp = Double.Parse(strTemp, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string result = temp.ToString("N1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Round off to 2 decimal places eg. 27.658 => 27.66

Ensure that there are always 2 decimal places eg. 12 => 12.00, 12.5 => 12.50

Good fit for currency amounts.

```
strTemp.ToString("F");
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, if you don't know how many the digits the variable could be, you can have a extension method:

```
public static string ToSpecificFormat(this decimal value)
{
    var count = BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(value)[3])[2];
    return value.ToString(count == 0 ? "N1" : "N" + count);
}
```

This will make sure there is at least 1 digit in the output.

For the second one, the selected answer will fail if the number > 1000000000. This one should work:

```
public static string ToFixedLength(this decimal value)
{
    if (value >= 1000000000m) return value.ToString("N0");
    
    var format = 9 - Math.Floor(value).ToString().Length;
    return value.ToString("N" + format);
}
```

output:

```
1.234m.ToFixedLength(); // 1.23400000
101m.ToFixedLength(); // 101.000000
123456789123m.ToFixedLength(); // 123,456,789,123
```